# comma delimited string collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

```
CommaDelimitedStringCollection commaStr = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();
string itemList = Convert.ToString(HIGList[i].AccountId) + '$' + "HIG" + ',' + '$';
commaStr.Add(itemList);
HigList = HigList + commaStr;
```

When i am trying to execute this it is showing **error** like

> Value may not contain `','`

Comment: What's **HigList** and **HIGList** ?

Comment: my function is this.
public bool SubmitWeeklySalesReportForSD(List<WeeklySales> HIGList)
{try
{
List<OracleParameter> parameter = new List<OracleParameter>();
 string HigList = null;
 for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < HIGList.Count; j = j + 2, i = i + 2)
{
CommaDelimitedStringCollection commaStr = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();
string itemList = Convert.ToString(HIGList[i].AccountId) + '$' + "HIG" + ',' + '$'; commaStr.Add(itemList);
                          HigList = HigList + commaStr;
                      }
                  }

Comment: What is itemList's value while adding?

Comment: itemList value is 461787$HIG,$

Answer (score 1):

`CommaDelimitedStringCollection` is intended to **generate** a comma delimited string. it means that you add values to it and when you call it's `ToString()` method, you get the values separated with a comma between each value.

That's why it won't let you add a value with a (non-escaped) comma `,` in it, as it violates it's very use.

For example:

```
var csv = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();
var cities = new[] { "New York", "Log Angeles", "Toronto", "San Francisco" };

foreach (var city in cities)
{
    csv.Add(city);
}

Console.WriteLine(csv.ToString()); // will output: New York,Log Angeles,Toronto,San Francisco
```

And in your case:

```
CommaDelimitedStringCollection commaStr = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();
string itemList = Convert.ToString(HIGList[i].AccountId) + '$' + "HIG" + ',' + '$';
commaStr.AddRange(itemList.Split(','));
HigList = HigList + commaStr;
```

Comment: @haim770, likewise, in your example, you could simply do `csv.AddRange(cities)` to add `cities` to the `csv` collection instead of the `foreach` loop.  Also, `Console.WriteLine` already calls `ToString` on the passed in parameter, so, there is no need to call `ToString` on `csv`. See the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is and it is immediately visible from the code... You're trying to add a string that contains a comma to a *comma delimited* string collection. Obviously this makes no sense so an exception is thrown.

Comment: but i need a comma there can you please suggest me what i need to do